# No Visible @interface for 'MainScene' declares the selector 'addGestureRecognizer:'

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to use Gestures in a game that I am working on and when I use the following code it is giving me the above error.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* up = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeUp)];

[up setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];

[self addGestureRecognizer:up];
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add Gesture Recognizers to views.

The last line in your code should be changed to:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:up];
```

Comment: Thanks Adam .. I found the answer. I should use the following code instead.

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:up];